# $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))dx$: Is my method a good one?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

So I decided to once again evaluate integrals for fun. After a while, I decided to start evaluating integrals that *seemed* like they might be undefined, but actually weren't. A while later, I came up with this:$$\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))dx$$and while I have evaluated said integral, I'm not sure if the result I got is actually correct. Here is my thought process for solving this bizarre integral:

---

First things first, we have to come up with a general solution for $\cos^{-1}(x)=a$. Here's how I did it:$$\begin{align}\cos(x)=&\;a\\\implies\dfrac12e^{-ix}+\dfrac12e^{ix}=&\;a\end{align}$$which implies that$$e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2a$$$$\implies e^{ix}-2a+e^{-ix}=0$$$$\implies e^{2ix}-2ae^{ix}+1=0$$and substituting $b=e^{ix}$ gets us$$b^2-2ab+1=0$$$$\implies b=e^{ix}=\dfrac{2a+\sqrt{4a^2-4}}2$$$$\implies e^{ix}=a+\sqrt{a^2-1}$$$$\implies ix=\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$$$$\implies\operatorname{arccos}(x):=-i\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$$Now, to get the general form for any $\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))$, we have$$\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))=\dfrac12e^{-\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}+\dfrac12e^{\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}$$$$=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac1{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}+x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$$$$\implies\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2-(x^2-1)}+x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$$$$\implies\dfrac12(2x\require{cancel}\cancel{-\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}})$$$$=\dfrac12(2x)=x$$which I got by going through the complex world. So now the integral is just$$\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}xdx=\left.\dfrac{x^2}2\right]_{-\pi}^{+\pi}=0$$which the indefinite integral for $\cos(\operatorname{arccos}(x))$ integrating with respect to $x$ is verified by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bcos%5C%2840%29arccos%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D).

---

### My question

---

Did I evaluate the integral correctly, or what could I do to evaluate it correctly/more quickly?

Comment: I suppose that, for you, $\cos^{-1}(x)$ is the same thing as $\arccos(x)$. Am I right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, you would be right.

Comment: Then I don't understand why is it that you use both notations. Furthermore, the domain of $\arccos$ is $[-1,1]$, and therefore your integral makes no sense.

Comment: You seem to go through a lot of trouble to show that the inverse of a function gives you $f(x) = x$, which is just the definition of a function inverse. But you forget about domain restrictions (you can't square root or take the log of a negative number), which obscures problems like how $\cos^{-1}(\pi)$ cannot take a value because the cosine is never bigger than $1$.

Comment: @MartianInvader Which is exactly why we go through the complex plane to get the definition of the inverse cosine function. In fact, you can actually plug in the integral into Wolfram Alpha and it will be understood perfectly fine (with it confirming my answer)

Comment: But if you’re using complex solutions, ln is multivalued and you must add arbitrary multiples of $2\pi i$ and you get various values for the cosine — adding an additional $\sinh(2\pi k)$ [I think; check this] for arbitrary integer $k$. Don’t rely on Wolfram Alpha to get multivalued functions right.

Comment: Note the inverse function $\cos^{-1}$ is defined to be a right inverse to $\cos$, so $\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))=x$ for all $x$ by definition.

Comment: @CrSb0001 You're using the notation for definite integrals, which assume all functions are real-valued. If you want to replace this with a complex path integral you can, but now you've got different problems because the functions sqrt(z) and ln(z) are not well-defined on the complex plane (they are multi-valued, so you need to choose branches of them if you want your computation to make sense). Note that just because Wolfram Alpha confirms your answer, it doesn't mean your reasoning is flawless.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the function you have provided is only valid in $[1,1]$ notice that whilst $f\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)=f^{-1}\left(f(x)\right)=x$ this is only true where the domains of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are satisfied. You may be interested to know that $\arccos(\cos(x))$ does not have this problem and can be simplified to $|x|$ over the real domain. Hope this helps!